# Leaflet getting a FeatureCollection into map fitBounds

Tags: leaflet

I have an array of polygon points which I add to a feature, which is then added to a Feature Collection, which I then use to calculuate the centroid using turf.centroid, this work fine.

```
const features = [];

var feature = {
    "type": "Feature", 
    "properties": {}, 
    "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [polygonlines] }
}

features.push(feature);
                    
var featCollection = {
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        features: features
}
```

But I am having trouble get the leaflet map to then move/zoom to include all the polygons in the features collection in the map bounds. I want to use flyToBounds or fitBounds but I am having trouble getting it working with the data I already have.

I have tried a few methods including the below but the bounds are not valid. Does my data need to be in a different structure/format to use the getBounds() function?

```
var bounds = L.latLngBounds(features);
mymap.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it:

```
    var feature = L.geoJson(featCollection);
    mymap.flyToBounds(feature.getBounds());
```